# Preventing concurrent method execution in Python

Tags: python, methods, concurrency, locking

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate. I did search around a bit, but maybe the wording I'm using isn't the best (I'm very new to Python)....

Anyway, here's the problem. I'm writing code for interacting with a temperature controller, which I want to represent this controller with a class with methods for setting the temperature and reading it---something like this:

```
class TempController:

    def getTemp(self):
        # some code ...
        return temp

    def setTemp(self, newtemp):
        # some code ...
        return newtemp

    def execute(self, method, newtemp=None):
        if method='set':
            return setTemp(newtemp)
        elif method='get':
            return getTemp()
        return None
```

Now, I'm going to have two objects calling methods on this object at the same time. What is the best way to make sure that if one is already `execute`ing, the other must wait until the first is finished? Does Python already ensure this? If not, the simplest possibility I've thought of is editing it like this:

```
    locked = False

    def execute(self, method, newtemp=None):
        while locked:
            'wait'

        ans = None
        locked = True

        if method='set':
            ans = setTemp(newtemp)
        elif method='get':
            ans = getTemp()

        locked=False
        return None
```

There should probably also be a timeout in the while loop, but I can worry about that later.

Thanks!

Comment: By "I'm going to have two objects calling methods on this object at the same time" do you mean two `Thread`s?  Because you only need to worry about concurrency issues if you're multithreading...

Comment: If you are using threads you probably want [threading.Lock](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects). If you aren't using threads or multiprocessing, then they aren't executing at the same time ( so there's no issue ).

Comment: Why does `execute` even exist? When could it ever possibly be a better idea to use `execute` than `getTemp` or `setTemp`?

Comment: @roippi There will not be any `thread`s. There will be an object whose purpose will be to run getTemp() roughly once per second and displaying the value. Starting (about) the same time will be a list of user-specified operations (including, possibly, the above) which will be executed sequentially. I know that the methods won't be _called_ at exactly the same time, but each call will take a finite time to return, so my fear was that one object would call `execute` while another's call was still running. (This actually _is_ a problem in LabVIEW, which is the "language" I'm trying to replace.)

Comment: @user2357112 It's there because I'm used to Java and its ilk and not used to the idea of storing actual _methods_ in lists :). The overall program will run 'experiments' by iterating over a list of actions on various instruments. In Java, I can store a reference to the relevant `Instrument` in each `Action`, but specifying which of the instrument's supported operations should be executed is harder (ultimately, I'd have used an `int` in each `Action` instance and some `public final static int`s in each `Instrument` subclass; each subclass would have `execute(int method,String[] params)`.